# CORS Not working (failed)net::ERR_FAILED)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

please help me. this not working. after call this method sms send properly but showing error this (failed)net::ERR_FAILED)

```
function sendSms(passWord, userName, smsRate, mType, MsgType) {
    var getMessage = $('.composeSMS').val(),
        number = '88'+$('[name="tags-input"]').val();
            var convateMessage = setConvertedMessage(getMessage);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'https://api.example.com:8443/sms/sms?',
            headers: {  
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': '*',
                    'Allow': 'GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS',
            },
            data: { source: mType, username: userName, password: passWord, type: 2, destination: number, message: convateMessage,format: "json"
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                conosle.log(data);               

            },
        });
}
```

[Error screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcWdk.png)

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not controlled by the consumer (the client browser) but by the provider (the cross origin server you are connecting to. CORS was introduced for security reasons, and there'd be no point if adding some headers completely disabled a servers ability to circumvent this security measure.

First thing to remove is the `Access-Control-*` headers from your request. These are **response** headers, and adding them to a **request** can result in otherwise functioning cross origin requests to fail - don't worry, this is a rookie mistake, you'll see this on stack overflow daily at least!

adding most headers will trigger an OPTIONS pre-flight check - which will fail if the server isn't expecting such a request

If, after you've made your your request is correct and has no extra (unexpected) headers in it, the request still fails, check the response headers - if there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response headers, then the server you are accessing does not allow browsers to make such a request

The solution then is to make the request from your own server, using server side code

As you have not mentioned anything about your server, let me try to help using some pseudo code

On the server you'd have something like

```
handle '/sms'
    incoming parameters: source, username, password, type, destination, message, format
    response = get(url { source, username, password, type, destination, message, format})
    return response to client
```

Comment: can you fix this problem ? if  you fix this problem, i will pay money

Comment: @MdAlaminSoriya I'm afraid I'm not in a position to do so for several reasons. a) I don't know what API you are using, perhaps there is a way to get CORS working with it. b) If not, I have no idea about your server side, for example, what languages you use (PHP? node? pythin? something else) on the server side. That is why I posted "pseudo" code, to give the general idea of what you need to do on the server